# How to deploy a Camunda modeled diagram into Camunda Tomcat

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I am trying to set up a BPMN workflow with Camunda. For this, I already made a diagram using the [Camunda modeler](https://camunda.com/download/modeler/). Now I want to open this BPMN diagram in Camunda. Camunda's Tomcat is installed  and running, but I can't manage to upload/ find the diagram in Camunda's Tomcat. I am currently trying this on my local machine.

Anyone who knows how to get a BPMN diagram into Camunda's Tomcat?

Comment: If you plan using GitHub actions for this purpose in future, I have published one opensource github action on the Marketplace. 

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/camunda-deploy-bpmn

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the ways to deploy described by @MuffinMICHI you can also deploy your diagram via the REST API. You just make POST request to /engine-rest/deployment/create 
You set Content-Type to:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

You set these parameters:

```
 deployment-name: <SOME NAME>
 deployment-source: <SOME NAME>
 data: <UPLOAD THE DIAGRAM HERE>
 diagram (optional): <UPLOAD IMAGE FOR DIAGRAM>
```

Answer (score 3):

a) You can deploy directly from the modeler to the server. 
https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/quick-start/deploy/
In the latest release the feature has improved further:
https://blog.camunda.com/post/2019/10/camunda-modeler-3.4.0-released/

[image]
On a local setup use rest endpoint `http://localhost:8080/engine-rest` if using on of the prepacked distributions or `http://localhost:8080/rest` if using Spring boot.

b) Process and decisions models (bpmn, dmn) can be auto-deployed. For instance placing the files into the *src/main/resources* folder (on a default Spring boot setup) will auto-deploy during startup.

c) There are other auto-deploy configuration options: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/spring-framework-integration/deployment/

d) You can use the REST-API, for instance with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to deploy. 
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/deployment/post-deployment/

Examples:

https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda-rest-postman

https://forum.camunda.org/t/process-deployment-to-rest-api-through-postman/10630

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways how you can upload your diagram to your BPMN engine.

1. In the Camunda Modeler, there is a little upwards-pointing arrow in the  menu bar. There you can specify where your engine is running and
   upload the diagram directly from the modeler.

   > https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/quick-start/service-task/
2. If you also have some `JavaDelegate`-classes you want to deploy with
   your diagram, you can pack all these things in a [WAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Archive)-file and put it
   in the `webapps`-folder of your Tomcat which will then
   automatically deploy your file.

   > https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/java-process-app/service-task/

The provided links guide you to the official Camunda documentation where all these things are explained in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy Camunda Process:-

> https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/quick-start/deploy/

[image: For local deployment from modeler to tomcat]

[image: Rest endpoint to deploy http://yourhost:yourport/rest(or /engine-rest)]

you can also use the play button to deploy if you are deploying the process for the first time.

***camunda-spring-boot-starter*** is configured to use the **SpringProcessEngineConfiguration** auto deployment feature by default.

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/process-applications/