# I try to deploy my process and I have wrong rest endpoint

Tags: camunda-modeler

I try to deploy my process and I have wrong rest endpoint,[I can't press the deploy button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajCAg.png)

what is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two basic problems that come to my mind.

- **You didn't start camunda.** If you are connecting to camunda through an app make sure that it's running. Try deploying again after your app is running successfully.
- **You are using the wrong port.** Make sure that camunda is running on port 8081 as you stated on your endpoint. You can check whether the port is used or not by entering the `netstat -an` command to windows cmd. Something with :8081 should show up if it's used.

Answer (score 0):

If you using an unmodified recent Camunda version then your REST endpoint URL is:
**http://localhost:8080/engine-rest**

Of course the server needs to be started / have started without errors.

Please also see:
[How to deploy a Camunda modeled diagram into Camunda Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789436/how-to-deploy-a-camunda-modeled-diagram-into-camunda-tomcat/58567916#58567916)